# How to look up a number in a table, based on another cell value in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel document for use by a student to calculate their grades. It is laid out in a user-friendly visual format where a cell has the name of the subject and underneath is the assignment name, raw score, score out of 100, etc. The final column is the letter grade (A-E) for each task. I need this column to update based on the grade cut offs for each respective subject.

So, if the subject is Chemistry, the GRADE cell should use the grade cut offs for the subject Chemistry as outlined in the DataTable sheet. In this sheet I have the subjects going across the top and the grades (A-E) down the side with the cells inside containing the MINIMUM to achieve that grade (e.g. the cell in the C row for Chemistry has 49 as that is the minimum score out of 100 to achieve a C.

Originally, I used this formula.

```
=IF(G9>=80,"A",IF(G9>=60,"B",IF(G9>=40,"C",IF(G9>=20,"D",IF(G9>=1,"E","")))))
```

where the cell G9 contains the score out of 100. However it would be too time consuming to change the numbers for every subject, and I would like the template to be flexible for use by many students, all of which study different subjects.

I also tried this formula.

```
=IF(G9="","",INDEX('B7'!B1:B5,MATCH(H8,'B7'!A1:A5,1)))
```

where the cell G9 is the score out of 100 and cell B7 is the name of the subject I was trying to look up (in this case Chemistry) on its OWN SHEET and the range B1:B5 is the grades A-E and the range A1:A5 are the cut offs for Chemistry.

**Here is how it currently looks in Excel (photos also attached)**

| **Assessment Task** | **Raw Score** | **Out Of** | **Weight** | **Score out of 100** | **Grade** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Data Test | 13 | 20 | 20% | 65 |  |
| Student Experiment | 20 | 20 | 30% | 100 |  |
| Unit Examination | 61 | 95 | 50% | 64 |  |

**Here is the GRADES sheet example data (the number in each box is the minimum score required to achieve that grade):**

|  | Physics | Chemistry | Biology |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 86 | 86 | 85 |  |  |
| B | 71 | 71 | 69 |  |  |
| C | 49 | 50 | 48 |  |  |
| D | 19 | 19 | 18 |  |  |
| E | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |  |

[image: How it currently looks in Excel]

[image: The GRADES sheet I want to reference]

Comment: You need a "2D Index Match" (search that term) where you use another Match to find which column to index into

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and your expected result (best by [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) - read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation). It is then much easier to help you.

Comment: @chrisneilsen I will look at the 2D index match now, thank you

Comment: @Ike I have edited the post to include the markdown table as requested, if that helps you better understand it?

Comment: @greg the min value for chemistry is 49 and not 50 as per your screenshot, is that a typo in your explanation?

Comment: Yes that was a typo my bad, I think I have fixed this now

Comment: Can you also post your expected output as well, so as i understand we are looking at Chemistry and extracting the grades and bounds for that specific subject and then are we going to compare with the `score out of 100` column is that so? Also what is your excel version may i know

Comment: The expected outcome is a letter grade (A-E) in the grade column, based on the score in the 'score out of 100' column and using the grade boundaries for each subject

Comment: @greg refer answer I have just posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try using <kbd>XLOOKUP()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F3</kbd>

```
=XLOOKUP(E3:E5,FILTER(DATASHEET!B2:P6,DATASHEET!B1:P1=GRADE_SHEET!A1),DATASHEET!A2:A6,,-1)
```

---

No need to fill down the formula, as it will spill down for the rest of the cells. However if you are not using **`Excel 2021`** or **`MS365`** then try the following:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F3</kbd>

```
=INDEX(DATASHEET!$A$2:$A$6,MATCH(1,
  1/(INDEX(DATASHEET!$B$2:$P$6,,MATCH($A$1,DATASHEET!$B$1:$P$1,0))<=E3),0))
```

---

**Note:** While exiting the edit mode of the formula, you need to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

---

Another way: Using <kbd>INDEX()</kbd> & <kbd>AGGREGATE()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F3</kbd>

```
=INDEX(DATASHEET!$A$2:$A$6,
  AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($A$1=DATASHEET!$B$1:$P$1)*(1/(DATASHEET!$B$2:$P$6<=E3))*
  (ROW(DATASHEET!$A$2:$A$6)-ROW(DATASHEET!$A$2)+1),1))
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

```
=INDEX(DATASHEET!$A$2:$A$6,
  MIN(IFERROR(1/($A$1=DATASHEET!$B$1:$P$1)*(1/(DATASHEET!$B$2:$P$6<=E3))*
  (ROW(DATASHEET!$A$2:$A$6)-ROW(DATASHEET!$A$2)+1),"")))
```

---

Comment: @greg glad to know it worked out for you, hence If this answered you question, please mark as correct by clicking the check mark beside the answer, so it helps someone in the future.

Comment: I wish I had access to `Filter` I'm still stuck with `Excel 2019` so my answer had to reflect that, lol

Comment: @todayimgonnalearn solutions shown below don't reflect with `FILTER` please check thoroughly only the first approach uses `FILTER`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer I've come up with:

First, let's create a subject table and give it an easy name, like "SubjectList"

[image: picture showing subject table]

(I understand that you have more subjects, but since it's a named table the formula will scale with it)

I like that you already have a table with all your Letter Grades lined up with your score requirements. We're just going to make one addition to that table.

[image: picture showing grade table with "active" column]

I call this the "Active" column, it uses an `Index(Match())` formula that changes based on a variable cell. In this case we have this:

[image: picture showing student lookup block]

The highlighted cell uses a `Data Validation` with `=SubjectList` as its Range Source. So, when you drop it down, you can choose which subject you want to look at and that will change the output for the "Active" column.

Now, onto some formulas.

In the active column we're using

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Grade[@[Physics]:[Biology]],,MATCH(StudentInfo[Subject],Subject[Subject],0)),"")`

[image: picture showing formula in color]

Here's the formula in color to help understand what's happening.
Basically, the "Active" column refers to the range of subjects @ the same row, in this case the subjects Physics through Biology, then uses the information chosen in the Subject dropdown in the student lookup, compares that to the SubjectList, and spits out the data from the column that's "Active" in the search.

Since everything is referenced to tables, you can autofill the rest of the rows for that column.

Now on to the actual Letter Grade lookup.
Sadly, I couldn't think of a more eloquent way of doing it than a general `Ifs()` formula.

`=IFS([Score]>=Q11,M11,[Score]>=Q12,M12,[Score]>=Q13,M13,[Score]>=Q14,M14,[Score]>=Q15,M15)`

[image: picture showing the formula for looking up the letter grade]

I get that you were trying to avoid a bunch of searches in the formula, and while this isn't perfect, I'd say that a formula with five searches is much better than 15-75 searches.

And again, this should be scalable, just make sure to add in your new subject columns to the left of the "Active" column and add them to your data validation list/table (I'd recommend adding them to the table since the data validation list should be based off the table).

Hope this helps, hit me up if you have any questions or I didn't explain something well enough.